# I need to get the parameter value?

Tags: c#, parameters, teamcity

I setup some parameters on `TeamCity`, so I can run different tests. 
Basically I append the parameter to the included section on `NUNIT build step`.

**Question is,**

1. can I get that `parameter value` so that I can use it in my code? (Based on the parameter value I have a switch statement to select a particular URL to use in test).

I've tried `string url = TestContext.Parameters["URLCODE"]` but no luck.

Is this possible? I see the parameter in the **NUNIT commandline**.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

I've looked all over the internet and cant find the answer.

Comment: Not the `TestContext`, you need NUNIT apis to access it or you need to supply the same as execution parameter and get it in `String[] args` of the Main

Comment: Can you also post how and where you are adding the Parameter in the `NUNIT build step`, edit your question and add a screen shot

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012954/how-to-access-teamcity-configuration-parameters-in-msbuild-unit-tests

Comment: @David what about using the env variable?